# Change Input's Blue Border Color into Red using css

Tags: css

as we know, when we click a text box, then, the will be blue border color, like below image[image]

And what I want is, if the user give a wrong input, then it will change into red, what is the name of this style in css?

Thanks.

Comment: Please try to explain in detail. Also let us know what erectly you want and what did you try so far?

Comment: "*as we know, when we click a text box, then, the will be blue border
color*". Not necessarily: HTML is just content/semantic structure, so it doesn't imply any presentation. Of course, most browsers have some default styles, but you can't rely on that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`:invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ainvalid) pseudo-class:

> The `:invalid` CSS pseudo-class represents any `<input>` or `<form>` element
>   whose content fails to validate according to the input's type setting.
>   This allows you to easily have invalid fields adopt an appearance that
>   helps the user identify and correct errors.

See [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/LwxcD/1/):

```
input:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1.5px 1px #0000FF;
} 
input:focus:invalid {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1.5px 1px #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: To make this consistent across browsers you should add `outline: none` so chrome doesn't cover the `box-shadow` with its own outlines.